# Is it possible to use the Angular DI framework in other applications?

Tags: node.js, angular, dependency-injection

Angular has a dependency injection framework that lets you autowire dependencies (similar to Spring Boot, etc.). Is it possible to use only the DI framework of Angular in a Node application, such as through an npm package?

Comment: As far as I'm aware it's baked into @angular/core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you like [Angular](https://angular.io/) concepts and look for a similar approach for backend side, have a look to [NestJS](https://nestjs.com/) which is a NodeJS framework inspired by Angular development style.

You'll retrieve [dependency injection](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers), and a lot of awesome ready-to-use features.

Comment: Thank you, sure will :)